# Generalizing field names with Gson

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I have a JSON objext that looks like this:

```
       {
               "isDefault": false,
               "someIndex":
               [
                   0
               ],
               "label": "Hello",
               "valueKindName": "someId",
               "value": 3,
               "conditions":
               {
                   "salesType":
                   [
                       1,
                       2
                   ],
                     "productType":
                   [
                       1,
                       5
                   ]
               }
           }
```

Now my Conditions class looks like this:

```
public class Conditions {

private List<Integer> salesType = new ArrayList<Integer>();
private List<Integer> productType = new ArrayList<Integer>();

}
```

This works. 
What I want to do is to generalize my class so that I could any new type to the conditions like:

```
   "exampleType":
                   [
                       6,
                       9
                   ]
```

without having to add

```
private List<Integer> exampleType = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

to my `Conditions.class`.

I have thought of the following:

```
public class Conditions {

    private ArrayList<Condition> conditions = new ArrayList<Condition>();
}
```

and

```
public class Condition {

    private String key;
    private ArrayList<Integer> values;
}
```

but Gson of course doesn't know how to convert the JSON to that type of data structure.

Any help would be highly apprectiated :)

Answer (score 1):

You can register your own converter.  It would look a little like this:

```
public class ConditionConverter implements JsonSerializer<Condition>, JsonDeserializer<Condition>
{
  @Override
  public JsonElement serialize(Condition src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context)
  {
    final JsonObject cond = new JsonObject()
    cond.add(src.key, context.serialise(src.values);

    return cond;
  }

  public Condition deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context)
      throws JsonParseException
  {
    // pick apart and make a condition again
  }
}
```

You then register the type adapter with your `GsonBuilder`:

```
builder.registerTypeAdapter(Condition.class, new ConditionConverter());
```

To pick apart your object, you'll need to use [`JsonObject.entrySet()`](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonObject.html#entrySet%28%29), as you don't know the key name beforehand.  Your job would be slightly easier if you adopted JSON like this:

```
{
  key: "exampleType",
  values: [ 42, 43 ]
}
```